# Unable to Disable Automatic Login on 13.10

Tags: login, 13.10, security

I have my settings as such, but when I power-on my laptop, it logs me right in, with no prompt.

Does anyone else have this problem?

[image]

Comment: The screen-shot shows the button as greyed out - therefore, just because it shows as off, it does not mean that is off. Are you using GNOME or Unity or what?

Comment: Unity.  A vanilla install of 13.10

Comment: The problem is the login manager, which will probably be lightdm. If your run `system-switch-displaymanager` as root, it will show you what display manger you are using. You may need to install 'system-switch-displaymanager' first - AND DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING WHEN YOU DO RUN IT, AS OTHERWISE YOU MAY HAVE SOME DIFFICULTY LOGGING IN, LOCKING SCREEN etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on my desktop after I had set on autologin and then set it off for myself.   Even though I set it off in the user settings box, it remained on and automatically logged my in without requiring a password.  I finally fixed it by locating and removing the following line in the /etc/group file: 
   "nopasswdlogin:x:118:username"

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the Display Manager configuration as root, using `nano`.

One of these for LightDM (I think that it is now default):

```
[wilf@comp ~]$ ls /etc/lightdm
keys.conf      lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf        users.conf
lightdm.conf   lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.old
lightdm.conf~  lightdm-kde-greeter.conf
```

It will probably be `lightdm.conf`, so run:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

For GDM (Gnome's)

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf
```

And for KDM (KDE's)

```
sudo nano /etc/kde/kdm/kdmrc
```

Look in the .conf files for 'Auto' - open each in a text editor (e.g. gedit) , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in each and type 'auto'

BEFORE ANY CHANGES ARE MADE, backup the configuration file you are editing:
For example, if you editing `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, run this first:

```
cp /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.old
```

Answer (score 1):

After a 13.10 vanilla Install, go to User Accounts 
Have a look to the unlock button (upper right corner)

After authentication, you will be able to switch Automatic Login to OFF

Comment: The unlock button was what I was missing! Thanks